# how to write a go test that need massive test case

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go

Let's say I have a list that has about 210000 english words.

- I need to use all these 210000 words as test case.
- I need to make sure every words in that list is covered every time I run my test.

The question is: What is the best practices to store these words in my test?

should I save all these words in a slice (will it be too large a slice? ), or should I save these words in a external file (like words.txt) and load the file line by line when needed?

Comment: There is no "right" or "wrong" answer to this, but I would store the words in a separate file, probably in a directory called `test/`.

Comment: 0.21M is not much for a slice unless you run on tiny hardware. If in doubt: measure.

Comment: @Flimzy Store the file in a folder named `testdata`, that is special and reserved for exactly this ([reference](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14715)).

Comment: @icza: Today I learned something new...

Comment: @Volker yes you are right, I think it's not much for a slice at that size

Comment: @icza thanks for pointing this `testdata` out

Comment: @Flimzy yes i think store the words in a separate file will be much neater

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test data is usually stored in a directory named `testdata` to keep it separate from the other source code or data files (see the docs from the command `go help test`). The `go` tool ignores stuff inside that directory.

210,000 words should take up only single digit megabytes of RAM anyway, which isn't much. Just have a helper function that reads the words from the file before each test (perhaps caching them), or define a [`TestMain()`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Main) function which reads them once and stores them in a global variable for access by tests that are subsequently run.

*Edit*: Regarding best practices, it's sometimes nicer to store test data in `testdata` even if the data isn't large. For example, I sometimes need to use multiple short JSON snippets in test cases, and perhaps use them more than once. Storing them in appropriately named files under a subdirectory of `testdata` can be more readable than littering Go code with a bunch of JSON snippets.

The slight loss of performance is generally not an issue in tests. Whichever method makes the code easier to understand could be the 'best practice'.

Comment: I think the idea of putting test data in `testdata` is fantastic, this is exactly the answer I'm looking for, thanks for your help.